# What is the Orientation of the "All-Sky" Projection?

Tags: astronomy, coordinate-systems, cosmic-microwave-background

The image below is the 9-year WMAP image (2012) of the cosmic microwave background radiation across the universe (from Wiki). As I understand it, the major axis represents the equator and the minor axis the central meridian. But, what is the orientation of the equator and central meridian relative to the earth ? In other words, how do I know where I'm looking ?

[image]

Comment: Might help? http://usersguidetotheuniverse.com/index.php/2013/03/26/i-get-mail-why-are-maps-of-the-universe-drawn-as-ellipses/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just a [Mollweide projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollweide_projection) of the [celestial sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_sphere) (or to be more accurate, of the [surface of last scattering](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Glossary/Essay_lss.html)).

The usual convention is to use the [equatorial coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equatorial_coordinate_system), so the major axis of the ellipse represents the projection of the Earth's equator. The minor axis of the ellipse is usually [right ascension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_ascension) = 0<sup>h</sup> or 0°, but I guess RA = 12<sup>h</sup> or 180° is also a reasonable choice.

### Update

Oops! As Thriveth mentions in the comments, it appears that the usual coordinate system used for CMB is the [galactic coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_coordinate_system), which is a spherical projection centred on the Sun. The equatorial plane of this projection is approximately the [galactic plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_plane) of the Milky Way, with the centre of our galaxy (the radio source Sagittarius A*) in the centre of the map.

It's difficult to determine the true galactic plane, since that's dependent on the distribution of all the mass of the galaxy, so the galactic coordinate system is defined in reference to radio observations of galactic neutral hydrogen through the hydrogen line.

Comment: I may be wrong but I believe the convention for the CMB maps is actually to have them arranged along Galactic coordinates, so the "equator" is the Miolky Way disk. See e.g. http://wmap.gsfc.nasa.gov/media/101082/index.html for comparison.

Comment: @Thriveth It looks like you are most likely correct. :oops: Thanks for that info!

Comment: So does this mean that the center of the CMB projection is in the direction of Sagittarius A*? And which way would "up" on the projection be? Galactic "up"?

Comment: @Aaron Yes, the centre of that CMB map is in the direction of Sag A*. I can't give you any more info than what's in the linked Wikipedia article on the galactic coordinate system. Click on the images in that article for higher res views.

Comment: `+1` but "...in the centre of the map." is confusing me.

Comment: @uhoh Draw a straight line from the centre of the Sun through the centre of the galaxy. Now imagine that you're at the centre of the Sun (& the Sun is transparent) and you're looking along that line towards Sag A*. Anything on that line gets projected onto the centre point of our map.

Comment: oh got it; the *direction towards* Sgr A* is the center of the map. Thanks!